# Unable to upgrade to the latest version of Orbeon forms (2019.1 CE)

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to upgrade Orbeon forms from version 2017.2 CE to the latest one (2019.1 CE) using a MariaDB (10.1) relational database  and I'm getting the following error message when I run the upgrade scripts:

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

I suppose that this is caused by the fact that the indexes that are to be created contain multiple fields with VARCHAR(255) using the collation utf8mb4.

In this case, is there any available workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct: this is due to a combination of the indexes containing multiple strings, `utf8mb4` now being used to store text, and the version of MariaDB you are on limiting the size of the max key length to 767 bytes. You can solve this issue either by:

- Upgrading MariaDB. On the MySQL side, the key prefix length limit is 3072 bytes for InnoDB tables since MySQL 5.7, initially released about 4 years ago as of this writing (October 21, 2015). I'm not sure when (or even if) that change made it to MariaDB. Hopefully you can find this information, and I'd recommend you explore this option first.
- Changing the DDL that ships with Orbeon Forms to use `utf8` character set instead of `utf8mb4`.

For more on this, see the first bullet point in the [MySQL versions](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db#mysql-versions) section.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I've finally used utf8 character set.

Comment: Got it George; this is most likely the fastest way to solve this problem, and it is fine if you don't need to support Emojis or other special characters (that require true UTF-8 support, implemented by `utf8mb4`).